# How to assign ones and zeros to specific indices of an array using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I wanted to construct a 6 x 9 matrix with entries zeros and ones in a specific way as follows. In the zeroth row column, 0 to 2 should be 1 and in the first-row column,3 to 5 should be one and in the second-row column, 6 to 8 should be one, with all the other entries to be zeros. In the third row, element 0,3,6 should be one and the other should be zeros. In the fourth row, element 1,4,7 should be one and the other elements should be zeros. In the fifth row,2,5,8 should be one and the remaining should be zeros. Half of the rows follow one way enter the value 1 and the other half of the row follows different procedures to enter the value one. How do extend this some 20 x 100 case where the first 10 rows follow one procedure as mentioned above and the second half follows different procedures

The 6x9 by matrix looks as follows

```
[[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
 [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]]
 EDIT: Code I used to create this matrix:
 import numpy as np
 m=int(input("Enter the value of m, no. of points = "))
 pimatrix=np.zeros((2*m +1)*(m**2)).reshape((2*m+1),(m**2))
 for i in range(2*m + 1):
    for j in range(m**2):
        if((i<m) and ((j<((i+1)*m) and j>=(i*m)))): 
           pimatrix[i][j]=1
        if (i>(m-1)):
           for k in range(-1,m-1,1):
              if(j == i+(k*m)):
                pimatrix[i][j]=1 
        if i==2*m:
           pimatrix[i][j]=1
 print(pimatrix)
```

Comment: What problems did you run into when making the assignments?

Comment: To clarify, SO is not a free coding site. Please make an effort to solve this, or show your work if you already have. Ask a specific question when you have one.

Comment: And what is the _general_ rule of your logic that can be both applied to 6x9 matrix as well as 20 x 100 matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `numpy.put` function [numpy.put](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach depends on the rules you plan to follow, but an easy approach would be to initialise the array as an array of zeroes:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([3, 4], dtype = int)
```

You can then write the logic to loop over the appropriate rows and set 1's as needed. You can simply access any element of the array by its coordinates:

```
a[2,1] = 1

print(a)
```

Result:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]]
```

Without a general rule, it's hard to say what your intended logic is exactly, but assuming these rules: the top half of the array has runs of three ones on each consecutive row, starting in the upper left and moving down a row at the end of every run, until it reaches the bottom of the top half, where it wraps around to the top; the bottom half has runs of single ones, following the same pattern.

Implementing that, with your given example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([6, 9], dtype=int)


def set_ones(a, run_length, start, end):
    for n in range(a.shape[1]):
        a[start + ((n // run_length) % (end - start)), n] = 1


set_ones(a, 3, 0, a.shape[0] // 2)
set_ones(a, 1, a.shape[0] // 2, a.shape[0])

print(a)
```

Result:

```
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]]
```

Comment: I have already written code for this but that was too long I feel. This code itself a part of another program. So I really want to know whether python can do this very easily in any other simple way.

Comment: It seems like you're asking about a smart algorithm rather than a Python implementation though. Also, I think your description in the question needs some further explanation. It's unclear what you expect to happen in larger cases and what rules you expect the solution to follow exactly.